# How can I make cron run a PHP script as www-data on ubuntu?

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, caching, cron

I have a PHP script that writes to several files for caching. The cache directory (let's call it /var/www/cache for simplicity) is owned by www-data:www-data.

I have the following cron job running every minute in www-data's crontab:

```
* * * * * php /var/www/my_script.php
```

The PHP file then uses file_put_contents() to  write my cache files.

My issue is that the created file is somehow owned by ubuntu:ubuntu and is therefore inaccessible to apache when it needs to read the cache files later and breaks my application.

How can I make my script save the files as owned by www-data:www-data so apache can read them?

Comment: I suspect something else is changing the owner. If the script runs as www-data, there's no way it can create a file owned by ubuntu.

Comment: That's what I suspected too, but I have no idea what could be going on. It's a Codeigniter application. The application ensures that the cron job is properly set up, then the cron job hits the index.php file once per minute with the controller and function name as parameters. This works and it creates the file properly, but it's always owned by ubuntu...

Comment: And this is a new server without any other applications or cron jobs that could be conflicting.

Comment: If the script does `echo get_current_user();` what does it show?

Comment: I finally gave in and rebooted the server, and this was fixed. Evidently there was indeed some process running in the background saving files as ubuntu, probably some old version of the script that I forgot I launched. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Try to manually set your user from php code.
Once you wrote inside file

do this

```
$path = "/var/www/cache" . $file_name ;
$user_name = "www-data";

// Set the user
chown($path, $user_name);
```